# Variable scope trought If /else if block

Tags: c#, scope

I have a problem. I wrote a console application for practice. The program asks repeatedly the user to type in a number, the program adds together the numbers and when the user types "done" the program divides the total with the entered numbers.

So my problem is. The program wont comply, because as you see i had to declare the int converted = int.Parse(input); into the else clause, because if user types numbers the program will skip the first 2 choices and converts the string into the number and the program continues as it should, but because i declared the int converted in to the else, the  converted in the else if, doesnt exist.

I know i have to put everything in the same bracket because of the variable scope, but how?

```
bool keepGoing = true;
int total = 0;

//The loop begins, repeatedly asks the user for  numbers.
while (true)
{

     //Asks the user for numbers .
    Console.Write("Type a number:");
    string input = Console.ReadLine();

    // When user types in quit the program quits
    if (input == "quit")
    {
        break;
    }


    // When user types "done", dividing total with converted(entered numbers).
    else if (input == "done")
    {
         total /= converted;
        Console.WriteLine(total);
        continue;
    }

    // If user types a number, convert into integer and add total and converted together.
    else
    {
        try
        {
            int converted = int.Parse(input);
            total += converted;
            Console.WriteLine(total);             
        }

        // Tells the user to type again.
        catch (FormatException)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Invalid Input, please type again");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: *program divides the total with the entered numbers* It does not seem as if your program tries to do what you've thought of. At best it divides the total by the *last* entered number. Is that the intended behavior?

Comment: Yup you are right, i just realised my mistake :) i should keep track of the entered numbers, right? i mean create an another variable and give +1 every time when the user types in a number, then divide that with the total?

Comment: Sounds reasonable to me :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Complete code block given here ->

```
    int total = 0;
    int converted = 0;

    //The loop begins, repeatedly asks the user for  numbers.
    while (true)
    {

        //Asks the user for numbers .
        Console.Write("Type a number:");
        string input = Console.ReadLine();

        // When user types in quit the program quits
        if (input == "quit")
        {
            break;
        }


        // When user types "done", dividing total with converted(entered numbers).
        else if (input == "done")
        {
            total /= converted;
            Console.WriteLine(total);
            continue;
        }

        // If user types a number, convert into integer and add total and converted together.
        else
        {
            try
            {
                converted = int.Parse(input);
                total += converted;
                Console.WriteLine(total);
            }

            // Tells the user to type again.
            catch (FormatException)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Invalid Input, please type again");
            }
        }
    }
```